# How to check that an array contains 1 to n^2 integers?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Let's say I want to check an 3x3 array and I want it to contain all the numbers from 1 to 9. I cant think of any efficient way other than the one I've written it down below. Is there a better way to solve this question?

```
int i, size, row, col, num = 1, valid = 0;

for(i=0; i<size*size; i++)
    for(row=0; row<size; row++)
        for(col=0; col<size; col++)
            if(num == arr[row][col]) {
                num++;
                valid++;
            }
```

Comment: I could use num -= 1; instead of valid though, but i think isnt quite logical

Comment: Define "better". Faster? Less memory-consuming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There is a better way.

It would be more optimal to use a boolean array instead of a third loop. Keep an array of booleans, initially all set to false. For each number found, mark the corresponding index in the array to true. At the end of your row and column loops, if all entries in the array are set to true, you found all the numbers.

To optimize even further, you could declare a counter variable. Each time you find a number, use your boolean array to check if that number was already found. If not, increment the counter. At the end of the loop, if the counter is 9, you have found 9 unique numbers.

You can even terminate early if you find a duplicate. This will increase performance further but only works if the number of unique numbers to find and the number of spaces for them to inhabit is the same. I.e. if you have 18 spaces and want to check for all numbers 1-9 this does not work.

Comment: Nice. And you could have a counter, which would be updated every time you would find a number, so that in the end you wouldn't have to scan the boolean array (well, not a big deal, since we would loop a 3D array initially...). :)

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot about adding another array. Thanks!

Comment: @Helpp no problem, happy to assist. if it helped please upvote and accept =]

Comment: You are welcome @nhouser9. FYI, new users cannot upvote until the reach a rep-threshold.

Comment: Why not using the boolean table as a duplicate detector ?
if you found a number and the corresponding index is false, you mark it true and continu. If you found a number and the corresponding index is true, you can stop your loop since there is a duplicate on the 3*3 entry array. For an 3*3 entry array, it's meaningless but for a K*K*K array with a big K, it can be usefull to not compute all the array. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @nbhouser9 Regarding your last edit : You can implement a counter duplicate for detecting impossible solution early.
If you have 18 space and want to check 1-9, this means you can have 9 duplicate max. After detecting a duplicate, you decremente the counter, and if the counter is less than 0, this means there is not all the number in the array. For the 3x3 case, the duplicate counter must be initialized to 0 if you want 1-9.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
bool nums[9] = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};

for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row) {
   for (int col =0; col < 3; ++col) {
      if (arr[row][col] < 1 || arr[row][col]> 9 || nums[arr[row][col] -1]) {
        // Number is out of range or previous it)
        break;
      }
      nums[arr[row][col] -1] = true;
   }
}
```

Where `nums` store true if the corresponding value has been found.

Comment: Isn't that the same with nhouser9's answer, or I am missing something? :)

Comment: Nope, it's pretty much just a straight copy of my idea =p

Comment: I was writing it at the same time

Comment: Well @nhouser9 I believe he wrote it without having seeing your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to loop through the `k`-times-`k` array and sum all the elements. Ensure that the resulting sum equals `1+2+...+n = n*(n+1) / 2`, where `n = k*k`. This coupled with the condition that all elements be unique (and positive) ensures that the array contains all and only the elements in `{1,2,...,n}`.

For `n=9` you'd check that the sum equals `45`. For small `n` you can use bit masks to check whether a number has been seen already: `if (n & (1 << current_number)) { seen; } else {not yet seen; mark as seen via n |= (1 << current_number); }`

Comment: Oh boy, that's a super-strong assumption. In 3D array having n² unique elements...

Comment: IMO this sort of defeats the purpose. You are assuming that the array has unique elements, which is basically something OP is trying to prove. We can't assume that.

Comment: Indeed. This would fail at the array `{0, 3, 3, 4...` as well as the array `{2, 1, 3, 4...`

Comment: There is a big misunderstanding here. I am not _assuming_ anything. I said that you would _have to check_ that the array also contains unique elements (and proposed to do that using bit masks). I said, "... _coupled with the condition_ ..."

Comment: Please, do take the time to thoroughly think through (and actually understand) an answer before you downvote it.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop isn't needed and you can stop searching when you find the first non-matching item. Unless you for some reason need a list of all the non-matching items, which doesn't seem to be the case(?).

Further micro-optimizations can be done if you know that the dimensions are always small. In this example they are assumed to be <256:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_arr_ok8 (uint_fast8_t row, uint_fast8_t col, int arr[row][col])
{
  uint_fast8_t count=1;

  for (uint_fast8_t r=0; r<row; r++)
  {
    for(uint_fast8_t c=0; c<col; c++)
    {
      if(arr[r][c] != count)
      {
        return false;
      }
      count++;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

The most important here is that the inner-most loop corresponds to the inner-most dimension. You could as well do it the other way around, and it wouldn't affect the algorithm, but it would give much worse data cache performance.